# Missing PLU Deposit on Coinbase

Tags: metamask, coinbase

On May 8, I have initiated a transfer of 17.57 PLU from my Metamask Wallet to Coinbase account/address. Initially, the transfer appeared to go through smoothly as it was confirmed within seconds by the network. However, it never showed up in my Coinbase account balance. I immediately reached out to Coinbase support to find out what was happening.

tx in question: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1bf295c721c77dca62929c2a92ac710fae30a3be7c12cebd96ee474e861055a3

Coinbase's response was that the address I used for the transfer isn't associated with **any** Coinbase account, and they suggested that it might be a browser-related issue. They mentioned that addresses can change over time, which could explain the discrepancy between the address displayed on my mobile app and the web version. However, they claim that this was not an address from them.

[image: Screenshot from computer with Address used to transfer]

[image: Screenshot from mobile where another address is displayed]

To shed some light on the situation, I have attached screenshots from both my mobile app and the web platform, clearly showing the address used for the PLU transfer. How can I provide evidence to Coinbase that the address I used for the transfer was indeed associated with their platform at the time of the transaction? I have noticed that at least two transfers were received by this address almost simultaneously, which makes me believe there might have been a technical glitch...